# where do I get shape files for javascript country world map?

Tags: javascript, maps, raphael, shapefile

I need to find a place where I can download shape files for javascript.

I mean this website:

http://raphaeljs.com/world/

uses `raphael.js` with a shape file of the us world:

http://raphaeljs.com/world/world.js

I just want to know how to get this file???

I need the js file for australia and new zeland.. also would be great if I can separate America in one shape and Asia in another one, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's SVG file and you have to convert from a vector file into draw command with js. You can convert an image to raphaeljs from here `http://readysetraphael.com/` . If you want to get the shape of Australia you can take a look at the file. some thing like this

```
AT: "M510.996,97.278l-0.257,1.158l-1.545,0l0.643,0.643l-0.900, ....
```

Comment: If this is not what you want, plz let me know

Comment: yes!!!!! thanks!!!!!!!!! thanks you!!!! the website is just great!! I know the code has the coordinates of australia but I needed the australia map divided into states, but with this can be an easy job!!! thanks

Answer (score 1):

Raphael site has an australian map ready and waiting for you - 
view source on their example page: http://raphaeljs.com/australia.html
and you can see all the state coordinate values.

Comment: yeah looks great!! thanks... but I would like to know where I can find this coordanates or the data to get that map.. cause I need a more custom autralia map.. with new zeland..